# Azure: Create alert when Maximum number of Workers is reached

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

In Azure, I enabled all `Diagnostic Logs` of my Databricks Workspace. I looked at all table, especially `DatabricksClusters` and `Usage` however, I didn't find any entry that would help me to create an alert when the maximum number of workers is reached.
I want to monitor databricks to find out when I have to increase the upper worker limit/SKU.

Comment: Do you have Unity Catalog enabled?

Comment: yes i have it enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few approaches to that:

1. Use diagnostic logs with Log Analytics. Diagnostic logs include [cluster events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs#--clusters-events) from which we can use `resize` and `resizeResult` fields.  The `resize` is primarily used by DLT pipelines, for all other clusters we need to use `resizeResult` event which includes `clusterWorkers` field with the number of workers allocated after resize.   The main problem with this approach is that this event doesn't include the information about `max_workers` field, so you will need somehow join `create` and `edit` events to obtain max workers, but this could be problematic if changes to the cluster configuration were done a long time ago, and no information is kept in the log analytics.
2. Recently Databricks started a public preview of [so-called system tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/system-tables/) that contains the same information as in the diagnostic logs (and more tables are coming), but it's stored for a longer time, so it's easier to join events like `resizeResult` with cluster information.  Then you can use [Databricks SQL Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/user/alerts/) to send notifications.  You can find more information about system usage for notifications in the [recent blog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/improve-lakehouse-security-monitoring-using-system-tables-databricks-unity-catalog) that also contains reusable queries, etc.
3. Setup project [Overwatch](https://github.com/databrickslabs/overwatch) that consolidates diagnostic logs + cluster logs + some other information to provide better insights into what happens in the workspace & individual clusters.  But Overwatch is slowly being replaced by system tables.